# Missing bitmap from camera image

Tags: android, bitmap

Actually have some problem to get bitmap from my camera
My code:

```
private Bitmap loadBitmap(Uri imageUri) {

    float dw = 720;
    float dh = 600;

    Bitmap returnBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) dw, (int) dh, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactorOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmpFactorOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        returnBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri), null, bmpFactorOptions);
        int heightRatio = (int) Math.ceil(bmpFactorOptions.outHeight / dh);
        int widthRatio = (int) Math.ceil(bmpFactorOptions.outWidth / dw);
        if (heightRatio > widthRatio) {
            bmpFactorOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
        } else {
            bmpFactorOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio;
        }

        bmpFactorOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        returnBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri), null, bmpFactorOptions);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.v("ERROR", e.toString());
    }

    return returnBmp;
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera = Camera.open();
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    List<String> colorEffects = parameters.getSupportedColorEffects();

    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

    } catch (IOException exception) {
        camera.release();
    }
    camera.startPreview();
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {

}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
}

public void BitMap(View v) {
    camera.takePicture(null, null, null, GetPhoto.this);
}

public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    Uri snap = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());
    bmp3 = loadBitmap(Uri.parse(snap.getPath()));
    canvas = new Canvas(bmp3);
    paint = new Paint();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp3, 0, 0, paint);
    test.setImageBitmap(bmp3);
    photobit=bmp3;
    Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, bmp3.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    t.show();
    try {
        OutputStream imageFile = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(snap);
        imageFile.write(data);
        imageFile.flush();
        imageFile.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Toast td = Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        td.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast td = Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        td.show();
    }
    camera.startPreview();
}
```

When i call my bitmap method

```
public void BitMap(View v) {
    camera.takePicture(null, null, null,  GetPhoto.this);
}
```

i get transparent bitmap on output 
where can be my problem?
My class implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.PictureCallback

Comment: Oh forget this(fined today that) i'm get error after call my bitmap method
12-20 11:43:34.461: V/ERROR(17621): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /external/images/media/8732

Comment: So that's mean that my
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) method don't catch the image for bitmap converting 
i'm right?